# Display only 2 digits after decimal

Tags: java

```
bill[p][l][0] = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(Double.parseDouble(i2[m][0]));
```

The code entered above is not working; input `10.0` gives `10` as output.

Comment: Have you tried `DecimalFormat("0.00")`?

Comment: it is a string array variable

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 have you? :P

Comment: vefthym - i unable to understand it

Comment: @vefthym I most certainly have not! I'm guessing that means the format string i specified doesn't work in java? (I thought it was a c# question, you see!).

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 it was just a bad joke for your username. sorry for that!

Comment: @vefthym lol. Not taken any offence :0) Everyone seems to want a piece of my username.

Answer (score 5):

It is working - a # means the digit is only printed if it's relevant (see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)). Try using

```
bill[p][l][0] = new DecimalFormat("##.00").format(Double.parseDouble(i2[m][0]));
```

Comment: bill[p][l][0]=new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(Double.parseDouble(i2[m][0]));

Answer (score 3):

To format exactly up to two decimal places you should use `##.00`  as `##.##` will remove the trailing zeros from the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle both positive and negative numbers I would recommend using `BigDecimal` since `Double` technically doesn't have any decimal values to truncate. Try something like this:

```
new BigDecimal(i2[m][0]).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
```